# PDF to Jasper XML

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a PDF file (softcopy) which was created using *iText*. Now my company decided to use *JasperReports* for new release. I need to use that PDF file (softcopy) and need to design *JasperReports* template and need to populate data.

Do we have any plugin in *JasperReports* that can convert from PDF to *JasperReports JRXML* or what do I need to do? Any suggestions?

Comment: I think that you should create the report template manually

Answer (score 3):

> A PDF is a description of how to render a document on a page. Things
>   like "draw a vertical line here", "write 'foo bar baz' here in
>   Courier". It does not contain any information about the format or
>   organisation of the stuff it is rendering. You won't be able to tell
>   that you're looking at a table, or a list of bullet points, or a
>   paragraph, or anything like that.
>
> The PDF format does contain information on a page-by-page basis.
>   Therefore, page breaks are the one piece of format/organisation
>   information that you can find.
>
> If you want anything more than a raw stream of completely unformatted,
>   disorganised text, one per page, you are out of luck. **It's virtually
>   impossible.**

from [javaranch](http://www.coderanch.com/t/278728/Streams/java/convert-PDF-file-XML-file)

Comment: But not completely impossible. With enough research into artificial intelligence, a reverse engineering agent could figure it out. They will need to massively increase their R&D budget over the next several years... but the payoff could be fantastic. (Or they could manually write the report and be done tomorrow.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://xmlprinter.com/ and then use a xslt to transform the resulted xml to the desired jrxml.

I'm working in it. If I finish it, i will post the result on github or any other public and open place.

Good Luck

Comment: 5 years passed... any news? have you finish it?